# Limit line length with monolog

Tags: php, monolog

I'm using monolog to log API requests. Some of those log messages include fairly large payloads. I would like to keep the general verbosity, but cut off all lines at 300 characters. Is it possible to configure monolog accordingly?

Comment: It is possible to limit the size of context (e.g. your payload) BEFORE you pass it to monolog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a processor in order to do it (https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md#adding-extra-data-in-the-records) :

```
$logger->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
    $record['message'] = substr($record['message'],0,300);
    return $record;
});
```

Comment: Best way if I'd like to read message max length from `config.yml`?